# How to separate Meteor project into modules

Tags: meteor

My Meteor project has two part:

1. Home page: can be visited by anyone.
2. Admin Console: provide some management tools to administrator only

When I running this project in production mode:

```
$ meteor --production
```

Meteor will combine all the client side code into one big file, that make "Admin Console" code also delivered to normal visitors.

Is there any way to "minify" javascript/css files into two files? 
one for normal visitor, one for admin?

I also pack this project into Android package, "Admin Console" code also exists in apk file, how can I exclude them ?

Thanks.

Comment: Currently, no. You'd need to create separate apps and run them on different domains/subdomains.

Comment: Or, you can try using `anti:modules` package. It's still in heavy development stage though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use meteor dynamic imports to only download code to the client based on the view the client is using. I have not tried this yet, but it should be possible to not load files dynamically based on the user's role.

Something like:

```
//must be called inside a meteor method or publish function
async function adminOnlyApi() {
  if(Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId, ['admin']) {
    return await import('path/to/lib');
  }
  return {};
}
```

Assuming the lib exports a default object with a key 'foo' and value 'bar', calling adminOnlyApi.foo when logged in as admin should return 'bar', and return undefined when logged in with any other user...